# How to convert RevealedOffset to number in flutter dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a phase in my codes like below

```
if (viewport.getOffsetToReveal(object, 0.0) > 10.0) {
    ...
}
```

`viewport.getOffsetToReveal(object, 0.0)` basically return a `RevealedOffset` object therefore I was not able to compare it with `10.0`.
It works in Flutter 0.5.1, but not 0.6.0.

How can I convert `RevealedOffset` object to a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume

```
viewport.getOffsetToReveal(object, 0.0).offset > 10.0
```

is what you are looking for.